# Parallel for-loop in shell script for all major OS

Tags: loops, shell, parallel-processing, operating-system

I am using a shell script to compile multiple .tex files automatically. But compiling them sequentially takes very long, especially because I need to compile them multiple times for correct output. Here is a short snippet:

```
#!/bin/bash
for file in *.tex
do
    pdflatex ...
done
```

I tried a solution with `xargs` but I was told, that this does not run on macOS. Sadly I did not find a solution that works on all major OS (Windows/ms-dos, macOS, Linux/unix). Can you give me a solution? I only use Linux and can't test other systems, but it has to work on them.

Comment: xargs is fine on macos.   What you were told is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My immediate though was: Why not use [`make`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Make_(software))? Then you can run all jobs on 8 cores like this:

```
make -j8
```

On the other hand, you can just start each process in the background. You won't have any control about the number of cores to use, though, unless you put in a lot more effort:

```
#!/bin/bash
for file in *.tex
do
  pdflatex ... "$file" &
done
```

Comment: Is it possible to wait until all background processes are done using ```&``` at the end? Edit: Using ```wait``` after the for loop waits until all background processes are done, which solved my problems. Thank you very much!!!